# RecyclerView adapter is not inflating the xml layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, picasso, android-gridview

I have collection of image links which I have stored in an array list and passing it to the constructor of adapter for further processing.

I want to show the images in RecyclerView using Picasso.

> But when I run my app the Toast message appears "Successfully Downloaded", but no image view shown on my UI(snapshot is shown below).
>   [image]

Below is my adapter

```
public class ImageViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

ArrayList<MovieDetials> dataList;
Context c;
public ImageViewAdapter(ArrayList<MovieDetials> list, Context context){
    dataList = list;
    c = context;
}
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.imagelayout,parent,false);
    MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return myViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Picasso.with(c).load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500"+dataList.get(position).getPoster()).into(holder.imageView, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Toast.makeText(c, "Successfully Downloded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataList.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }
}

}
```

imagelayout.xml is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:contentDescription="An image"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**I am using Grid Layout Manager to view the images(Below is it's code)**

```
adapter = new ImageViewAdapter(data,this);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2));
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Use default / error images to check if the views are displaying

Comment: @user3374345 the views are not displaying even after adding default images

Comment: Set background to your recyclerview to see if its showing ... Check your xml thoroughly

Comment: @user3374345 Got it, I had set the height of recycler view to wrap content but changing it to match parent works

Comment: Glad it works..

Answer (score 1):

Change `RecyclerView` height to `match_parent`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ...
    />
```